# Ubuntu 20.04 system freezes and screen goes crazy

Tags: 20.04, crash

My Ubuntu 20.04 completely freezes randomly (sometimes 15 min after boot, sometimes after 1 hour / 2 hours) with noise patterns on screen.

https://youtu.be/nvwx3uSbM_k

I have changed the ram and this is still happening. I don't have any graphics card installed. My computer has Intel Core2Duo CPU and 4 GB ram. The CPU and RAM usage is not high when this problem occurs. Also I used lm-sensor program in Ubuntu 20.04 to check whether it was temperature issue, but according to it the temperature was between 50 to 60 deg Celsius. Any idea on why this could be happening would be helpful.

Comment: With such old hardware anything can happen.

Comment: I'd guess the problem is RAM (video or general), or failing power supply. Those are the things I've seen produce this sort of issue on older hardware.

Answer (score 0):

As an owner of old Thinkpads I refrained from using **Gnome** on them, since it uses up too much memory.

Instead you should switch to "Xubuntu" or an "LXQT" variant (which is a little harder to maintain).

Xubuntu offers the same or similar software packages as Ubuntu (with Gnome), using the XFCE4 desktop, which is comfortable and lighter on your resources